# Mocking in Scala test is not working, actual method is getting called

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

Mocking in Scala test is not working, actual method is getting called

```scala
    test("test generateEdgeForRegion method") {
      val mockobj = mock[GraphElementGeneratorService]
      val jsonString = CreateJsonRecord.getJsonFromFile("/ResponseForRegionEdgeUpdationTest.json")
      val generatorService = new GraphElementGeneratorService
      when(mockobj.getToken()).thenReturn("pnt95greg178pkagkmj28g35tnkh43pg")
      when(mockobj.getRefDataURL("baseUrl")).thenReturn("http://dbvrt28887:9000/graph/EnterpriseProvider/edges")
      generatorService.generateEdgeForRegion(jsonString, region)
    }
```

Comment: Check inside the method with what arguments the method is being invoked. In test check what arguments are being passed in the mock statement. Both should match.

both methods getToken and getRefDataURL are not kocked or any one of them?

Comment: Where is object `mockobj` used? Did you mean to use it as `mockobj.generateEdgeForRegion(jsonString, region)` ?

Comment: getToken() method has no argument, for getRefDataUrl, I am passing the exact parameter.

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc, No generateEdgeForRegion is a method inside which I have getToken() and getRefDataUrl methods are present.I want to mock getToken and gerRefDataUrl using mock object of GraphElementGeneratorService.All three methods are present in GraphElementGeneratorService class.

Comment: @Sudeep that's a wrong usage of mocks, you may be able to achieve that with a spy, but imho the whole test is wrong, if you are testing `GraphElementGeneratorService` you shouldn't have to alter any part of it. I'd take a second look at your design if I was you

Answer (score 0):

The test code you have is creating 2 different "instances" of `GraphElementGeneratorService`. I say "instances" because one is a mock, and the other is an actual instance. They will have absolutely no relationship to each other, so providing return values for specific method calls on the mock will have no effect on the real instance.

Look into `thenCallRealMethod()` as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4588159/1365044), or consider refactoring your code such that `getToken()` and `getRefDataURL(...)` are methods on some object that gets provided to `GraphElementGeneratorService` as a constructor parameter. That way the real code can pass in a real object there, and your test code can pass in a mock. Then your `when(...).thenReturn(...)` statements in the code you pasted will work (as long as `mockobj` is a mock of this new class that you pass into `new GraphElementGeneratorService(...)`)